# Call 64 bit process from 32 bit process

Tags: c#, .net

Can a 64 bit process be called from 64 bit process using Process class provided by .Net? Please note that both the cal-lee and processes are .Net processes. So, the caller process is built to target x86 and cal-lee process is built under Any CPU configuration.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why not try it and see?

Comment: You want IPC, the `Process` class doesn't do this for you.

Comment: I tried, it gave me error during execution. So, I recompiled the callee process to x86 and it worked. I am not sure why it didn't work when calle ewas built with Any CPU option.

Answer (score 0):

If the operation system allows to start both, 32 and 64 processes (if you have a 64bit os) you can do it with the .net `Process` class. Because you just use operation system function over the .net framework.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about launching another process by using .Net Process class, the answer is below.

If caller is built as x86 and callee is built as AnyCPU, callee will be launched as x86.

If caller is built as x86 and callee is built as 64bit, callee will not launch.